# How to generate a full code map for the solution in Visual Studio 2012?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, mapping, visualization

I want to know how to generate a full code map for the solution in Visual Studio 2012?

I want code visu

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know this is not possible (with a out of the box vs) for entire solution, only for projects you can get code map.